# HP Touchsmart 3000-1020 hardware issues

Tags: hardware-failure, desktop-computer, hp-desktop-computer

I have an HP Touchsmart 3000-1020.  The problem with it is that the fans speed up immediately after being turned on.  I used to be able to get on for a few minutes before it would shut the whole thing down, but now the monitor won't even turn on.  I tried doing a bit of research and repairing it myself, but I haven't been able to fix it.

First, I found this website ([here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/TouchSmart-PC/HP-Touchsmart-300-1020-Powers-up-blank-screen-never-boots/td-p/807339)).  I thought that my hard drive was the problem, so I had it replaced.  I'm pretty sure that the hard drive was not burned-out because nothing changed when I started the computer up.

I recently came across several websites that claim that the problem is the heatsink/fan.  So, I opened the computer up and looked at both fans as I turned it on.  One fan was working fine and quietly, but the fan connected to the heatsink for the CPU was speeding up and running loudly.  One thing I can't figure out is why the monitor won't even turn on so I can get into BIOS.

I have several questions:

1. Based on this, do you think replacing the fan to the CPU would solve the problem?
2. While testing the computer, I ran it while taking the fan out.  Do you think I have damaged the CPU by doing this?
3. Why won't the monitor display anything after starting up?  How can I resolve this?
4. If the fan IS the problem, do you know where I can order an exact replacement?

Answering any of these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the fan runs even if it is at high speed, the fan is ok, it is doing what it is being told to do.
2. That was not a good thing to do, the CPUs nowadays are thermally protected and will either throttle down or shut down in the event of it overheating. I would draw more concern the condition of the fan being removed while the computer is up and running. Maybe this one is an exception, but many fans I removed were not just a matter of lifting out. Delicate at best, is the way I see to describe the way they have to be lifted out. With the fan running, it makes it all more interesting.
3. Test your LCD screen and connection by hooking up an external monitor to the video jack on the side of the laptop and see if it displays something.
4. An exact replacement is available online, just Google your laptop model number or P/N with "CPU fan" after it. In other words, HP Touchsmart 3000-1020 CPU fan. You will find something that will work. Confirm THE part number for the fan by searching it on the HP website. There will be a place to see the service manual for that unit, it will have the part number you need. You can use this as a Google search too.  ALWAYS double check your source when shopping online. Using both of the search techniques I shown you, should get you the same result.